# Using orderBy with dataframes in spark(python)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I am not sure what is going wrong here. I am having a dataframe:

```
>DFexample.columns
>['url','weight1','weight2']
```

and I am trying to order in descending order from the `weight2`:

```
>DFexample.orderBy(DFexample.weight2.desc()).show(4)
>-----+--------+-------------------+
| url |weight1 |          weight2  |
+-----+--------+-------------------+
| x   |0       | 9.800000342342E-4 |
| x2  |1       | 2.432432432       |
| x3  | 1.2    | 2.134234234       |
| x4  | 1.32   | 1.232324          |
+-----+--------+-------------------+
```

Everything seems to be ordered except from the first value. For what reason would this happen?

Comment: Is it possible somehow, that your `weight2` column has `string` type instead of `double`? You can check this printing schema: `DFexample.schema`

Comment: Good catch. I forgot to assign type to `udf` so it took as default to be string.